# Bootstrap Toggle Burger Menu not working when switched to mobile view

Tags: php, html, css, menu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  px-2 " style="background-color:#E53935;">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HeadOverMeals</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cart</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.  It would help people to answer your question if you provided a few more details about what is going wrong, and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed these steps:
Step 1: Add proper "css" file inside the "header tag" and the "javascript" file at the end of the "body tag". You can find the links over here https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Step 2:Try copying the default navbar from the bootstrap website and then editing it.
You can find it over here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

I faced the similar problem and the step-1 solved it.